# Get user input from tk.Text and tk.Listbox without using tk.Button

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tkinter-text

I made a UI in Python with the `tkinter` library. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the user input from a `tk.Text` or `tk.Listbox` widget without using a button. I am trying to assign the user input to a variable that takes a permanent value as soon as  `root.destroy` is invoked with a button or the UI is closed manually. This works for widgets such as `tk.Entry` or `tk.Radiobutton`. I was wondering how I could get this to work for `tk.Text` and `tk.Listbox` widgets as well. An examplary code is shown below, hopefully it clearifies what I am trying to do.

```
# Import tkinter library
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Function to create root
def CreateRoot(Pos, Dim, Color, Text):
    Root = tk.Tk()
    Root.config(width = Pos[0])
    Root.config(height = Pos[1])
    Root.geometry(str(Dim[0]) + 'x' + str(Dim[1]))
    Root.config(bg = Color)
    Root.title(Text)
    return Root

# Function to add entry to root
# that allows one element
# from some given list 'Val'
def CombEntry(Root, Pos, Dim, Style, Var, Val):
    Entry = ttk.Combobox(Root)
    Entry.place(x = 1000 * Pos[0])
    Entry.place(y = 1000 * Pos[1])
    Entry.place(width = 1000 * Dim[0])
    Entry.place(height = 1000 * Dim[1])
    Entry.config(justify = Style[0])
    Entry.config(state = Style[1])
    Entry.config(font = Style[2])
    Entry.config(textvariable = Var)
    Entry.config(values = Val)
    return Entry

# Function to add entry to root
# that allows one or more elements
# from some given list 'Val'
def ListEntry(Root, Pos, Dim, Style, Var, Val):
    Entry = tk.Listbox(Root)
    Entry.place(x = 1000 * Pos[0])
    Entry.place(y = 1000 * Pos[1])
    Entry.place(width = 1000 * Dim[0])
    Entry.place(height = 1000 * Dim[1])
    Entry.config(justify = Style[0])
    Entry.config(state = Style[1])
    Entry.config(font = Style[2])
    Entry.config(selectmode = 'multiple')
    Entry.config(listvariable = Var) 
    Entry.insert(tk.END, *Val)
    return Entry

# Function to add entry to root
# that allows one line or more
# without further restrictions
def TextEntry(Root, Pos, Dim, Style, Var):
    Entry = tk.Text(Root)
    Entry.place(x = 1000 * Pos[0])
    Entry.place(y = 1000 * Pos[1])
    Entry.place(width = 1000 * Dim[0])
    Entry.place(height = 1000 * Dim[1])
    #Entry.config(justify = Style[0]) # Non-existent attribute
    Entry.config(state = Style[1])
    Entry.config(font = Style[2])
    #Entry.config(variable = Var) # Non-existent attribute
    return Entry

# Create root and add entries
dims   = [0.200,0.050]
style  = ['l','normal','Calibri 12']
root   = CreateRoot([0,0], [500,500], '#DDDDDD', 'Title')
tkvars = [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()]
entry2 = CombEntry(root, [0.025,0.025], dims, style, tkvars[0], ['A','B','C'])
entry3 = ListEntry(root, [0.025,0.100], dims, style, tkvars[1], ['A','B','C'])
entry1 = TextEntry(root, [0.025,0.175], dims, style, tkvars[2])
root.mainloop()

# Print user input without having used
# a tk.button with command
user_input = [i.get() for i in tkvars]
print('user_input = {}'.format(user_input))
print('\nnotice how user_input[0] is correct..')
print('but user_input[1] and user_input[2] are incorrect')
```

Comment: Why create widgets in functions?

Comment: @8349697 Because I need to create roots with tens or hundreds of widgets and most of these widgets have the same properties. Creating a widget by function reduces the length of my code, since I don't need to specify these properties each time. However, in some cases I need to deviate from some of these properties, so ending each function with 'return' allows me to customize these properties whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the last values entered in the widgets, you can use the protocol handler for the root window.

```py
# Import tkinter library
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

...

entry1 = TextEntry(root, [0.025,0.175], dims, style, tkvars[2])

# works when GUI is closed manually, close button [x], Alt + F4
# protocol handler
def close():
    # creating global variables in a function
    global combobox_value, listbox_value, text_value
    combobox_value = entry2.get()
    # entry3.curselection() is a tuple with the indices of the selected list items
    listbox_value = [entry3.get(i) for i in entry3.curselection()]
    text_value = entry1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    # optional, validation of values
    if not all([combobox_value, listbox_value, text_value]):
        answer = askyesno(title="Info", message="Not all values have been selected. " \
                                                "Close the application anyway?")
        if not answer: # False
            return
    root.destroy()
    
# exit with saving data
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)

root.mainloop()

# Print user input without having used
# a tk.button with command
print("User input:", combobox_value, listbox_value, text_value)
```

Comment: Your method does what I want. Thank you for your help, you can consider this question answered.